# MYSQL, script file is read with the wrong character map. How do I change it?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows

I run a MySQL client in windows console and I'm running an SQL script file using the source command. But some characters from the SQL script file gets distorted.

For example if I write the following in the my SQL script file:

```
INSERT INTO Unit (Unit, Symbol) VALUES ('CELSIUS', '°C');
```

When I run the SQL script file in my MYSQL client (using verbose):

```
mysql> source MYFILE.sql
```

I get this:

```
INSERT INTO Unit (Unit, Symbol) VALUES ('CELSIUS', '┬░C');
```

The degrees symbol is replaced with ┬░.

My question is, how can I tell it to read the file characters using a different character map?

The SQL script file is in UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invoke mysql with an option such as --default-character-set=utf8.

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```